# Excel VBA CountIF To Search For String Array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

How can I use the `COUNTIF()` function to count only certain text strings that exist in the range?

I tried to use the below, but I get an error of

```
Syntax error
```

This is the syntax I attempted

```
Dim worksheetmaster As String = "Master"
Dim worksheettocheck As String = "New"
Dim softcount As Int, i As Long, hardcount As Int

softcount = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(Range('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ")"Soft")")
hardcount = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(Range('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ")"Hard")")
```

**EDIT**
I tried to use this syntax without the `Range` and am still getting the error

```
hardcount = Evaluate("=COUNTIF('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ")"Hard"")
```

Comment: you dont need the range, it will be as it would in a worksheet.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - still got an error :( -- see my edit.

Comment: no , after each segment like `=countif('" & w1 & "'!A:A,"'" & w2 & "!A:A".....`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - que?

Comment: countif is (range,value) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836633.aspx

Comment: Why not use a for loop rather than using an excel function?

Comment: What is that trailing `"Hard"` supposed to do there?

Comment: @Addohm - my VBA skills are not the best, and thought it would be easier to use a pre-existing function to gather the count than to write customized

Comment: Doesn't hurt to ask.  The countif function is great to use if there is a massive amount of data, but it's certainly easier (in my opinion) to knock it out in VBA :)  Good luck!

Comment: @A.S.H - I added the second double quote, as I thought it may be needed to close of the double quote before the `=` sign at the beginning, and since the word Hard is a string I was enclosing it in double quotes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match in column `A` with `Hard` in column `B`, this is how it should be:

```
hardcount = Application.Evaluate("COUNTIFS('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A,'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ",'"  & worksheettocheck & "'!B:B, ""Hard"")")

softcount = Application.Evaluate("COUNTIFS('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A,'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ",'"  & worksheettocheck & "'!B:B, ""Soft"")")
```

Comment: I am wanting to get a count where column A on Master matches Column A  on new - but the value in Column B is Hard.  If I try your second syntax above it always gives a 0 result returned even thought it should be more.

Answer (score 0):

Your first syntax errors are here:

```
Dim worksheetmaster As String = "Master"
Dim worksheettocheck As String = "New"
```

You can't do that. Instead, you would need to use:

```
Dim worksheetmaster As String
Dim worksheettocheck As String
worksheetmaster = "Master"
worksheettocheck = "New"
```

Even better would be to assign them to point diectly at the worksheets, but let's work with your code as much as possible instead of totally rewriting it.

For the countif, you cannot join ranges that way. You haven't even assigned a value to i, but assuming i = 1, your code:

```
softcount = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(Range('" & worksheettocheck & "'!A:A'" & worksheetmaster & "'!A" & i & ")"Soft")")
```

evaluates to total nonsense in VBA:

```
softcount = Evaluate(=COUNTIF(Range('New'!A:A'Master'!A1)Soft))
```

Now, from what I can tell, what you are trying to do is to count how many times the value in cell Master!A & i appears in the range New!A:A, depending whether Master!A & i="Soft" or Master!A & i="Hard". So let's see if we can find code that will do that.

For data we enter "Soft" into Master!A1 and "Hard" into Master!A2. Then we enter random "Soft" or "Hard" into various cells in the column New!A:A.

Now your code looks like this:

```
Dim worksheetmaster As String
Dim worksheettocheck As String
Dim softcount As Long, i As Long, hardcount As Long

worksheetmaster = "Master"
worksheettocheck = "New"
i = 1
softcount = Application.CountIf(Sheets(worksheettocheck).Range("A:A"), Sheets(worksheetmaster).Range("A" & i).Value)
i = 2
hardcount = Application.CountIf(Sheets(worksheettocheck).Range("A:A"), Sheets(worksheetmaster).Range("A" & i).Value)
```

This is inefficient and limited, but it retains as much of your original code as possible, and it works.

Edited to add: if "Hard" is in Master!B & i instead of A & i then the code becomes:

```
i = 1
softcount = Application.CountIf(Sheets(worksheettocheck).Range("A:A"), Sheets(worksheetmaster).Range("A" & i).Value)
hardcount = Application.CountIf(Sheets(worksheettocheck).Range("A:A"), Sheets(worksheetmaster).Range("B" & i).Value)
```